# Access pod from external public url

Tags: kubernetes

I created this test helm chart which I want to access via public url domain:

```
https://github.com/rcbandit111/external_domain_helm_chart_poc/blob/main/pod-chart/templates/ingressresource.yaml
```

Ingress controller:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: registry-domain-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: monitor.somedomain.org
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ include "pod.fullname" . }}
                port:
                  number: 80
```

I added a record into public DNS register:

```
monitor.somedomain.org ->  4.4.4.4 (node1)
monitor.somedomain.org ->  4.4.4.5 (node2)
```

But when I try to open the url link page is not loaded. Any idea what might be wrong?